# Application Permissions

Tags: permissions

I note that with my Samsung S7 Edge now I have "[Permission Monitor](https://www.samsung.com/ae/support/mobile-devices/what-is-this-new-add-feature-app-permission-monitor-and-how-to-turn-off/)" as an option, which is great. Leaving out the whole root option (I don't want to risk it again, it was a $300 fix last time it 'broke') I am looking for a methodology to either:

- Allow me to globally **refuse** permissions to all applications or;
- Reset permission settings **each time** the application is used.

A typical use is I need Facebook (Yes, I know they have the data already...) to have access to photos for example. I enable it, and then never disable it. I want to limit (and this is basically **globally**) any applications capacity to interact with photos, videos and microphone.

- Samsung S7 Edge
- $10-30.00 budget for application
- Preferably not rooting, Android 7.0 (From memory)

Answer (score 2):

Non-root third party permission managers have to rely on inbuilt [appops](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AppOpsManager) permission manager. Because appops is not available for third-party apps but only the system apps, former usually resort to an [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) hack.

I use [App Ops - Permission Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rikka.appops) from *Xingchen and Rikka*, mostly because of its auto-apply template feature (the global restrictions you're looking for on all new installations). Furthermore, it also provides access to all permissions available under appops for any app, regardless whether the app requests access to such permission or not. It, however, doesn't "*reset permission settings each time the application is used*".

On first launch, the app would guide you how to setup adb to make the app work. The downside, not limited to this app but quite about every non-root third-party permission manager, is that if you reboot, you'd have to setup the adb hack again or your custom preferences for the apps would fail to work (note: the app itself would fail to work unless adb hack is setup again).